# Maintaining multiple class instances (objects) wihout destructor calls in c++

Tags: c++, oop, object, destructor

I want to make many objects of type "Student" and store them so they can be used throughout the program.  I'm also required to print out messages when a student is created and destroyed, but when i put the "destroyed" message in the destructor it'll appear whenever I change instance to create the next student cause the destructor is called. Is there a way to bypass that and only have the destructor be called for each object at the end of my program?

This current piece of code has each student destroyed whenever the next one is to be created (with each for loop), and then again "redestroyed" at the end of the program. I only want them to be deleted at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Student{  
    // members
public:

    Student(){}
    Student(std::string name, int floor, int classroom ){
        std::cout<<"Student created\n\n";
        // assignments
    }
    ~Student(){std::cout<<"Student destroyed\n\n";}
       // methods
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

Student* S=new Student[5];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    S[i]=Student("example", 1,1); //makes 5 students and stores them
}

// rest of the program

delete[] S;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think each student is being destroyed in the loop? You are storing them in an array.

Comment: Because when I run it, i see:

Student created

Student destroyed

Student created

Student destroyed

Student created

Student destroyed

Student created

Student destroyed

Student created

Student destroyed

Student destroyed

Student destroyed

Student destroyed

Student destroyed

Student destroyed

Comment: `S[i]=Student("example", 1,1);` creates a temporary object of type `Student`, initialised using the arguments `"example"`, `1`, and `1`,  assigns `S[i]` to become a *copy* of the temporary, and destroys the temporary.

Comment: Also, in standard C++ (since 1998) it is better to avoid (direct) use of operator `new` and `delete` - try learning how to do THAT before worrying about how often destructors are called.    It will make it easier, in a lot of cases, to avoid unnecessary construction and destruction of objects.

Comment: Add assignment operator code to your class and print when it gets called.

Comment: I ended up using vectors as a solution here indicated, so no need for new and delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor you see from the loop is not the array elements being destructed, but rather the *temporary object* that you create by `Student("example", 1,1)`.

The statement

```
S[i]=Student("example", 1,1);
```

is essentially equal to

```
Student temporary_object("example", 1, 1);
S[i] = temporary_object;
```

If you want to create five objects, where every object is initialized exactly the same (which is what you're doing) then use a `std::vector` with explicit initializer:

```
std::vector<Student> S(5, Student("example", 1,1));
```

This will still call the destructor once, for the temporary object you create in the `std::vector` constructor call.

---

There *is* a way to skip the creation of temporary objects, but that also requires the use of vectors:

```
std::vector<Student> S;
S.reserve(5);  // Reserve memory enough for five elements

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    S.emplace_back("example", 1, 1);  // Construct in-place in the vector,
                                      // no temporary object creted
}
```

Note that the `reserve` call is important to avoid reallocations of the vector, which involves possible copying of data and *destruction* of the old data.

Comment: Every object is initialized exactly the same only in this example, not in the actual program I'm making. So I used your solution with vectors to skip the creation of temporary objects, thanks! The vector gets deleted automatically so I don't need to worry about deallocating memory, right? 

Also tried it with 2 vectors of types Student and Teacher and the one I declared first seems to be deleted last, interesting.

Comment: @GeorgeT Yes the `std::vector` objects maintain their own memory, you don't need to do anything. Also, objects are destructed in the opposite order of definition (specified in the C++ specification).